# PHP temperature converter. Resource not found error

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a temperature converter that allows you to input into a text box, check a radio button and convert based on the radio button you check. However when the submit button is pressed it takes me to a page that says "the resource cannot be found" and it says there's an error finding the /converter which is the action of my form. I'm very new to this and couldn't find anything explaining how to fix it

```
<?php

@$input = $_GET['degrees'];
@$radio = $_GET['celorfar'];

 if($radio == 'far'){
$answer = ($input * 1.8) + 32;}
else {
$answer = ($input - 32) * .56; //.56=5/9
}




echo <<<END_OF_FORM
<form method="GET" action="converter">
<input name="degrees" type="text" />
<br />
<input name="celorfar" type="radio" value="far" /> Convert to Fahrenheit<br />
<input name="celorfar" type="radio" value="cel" /> Convert to Celcius<br />
<input name="Convert" type="submit" value="Convert" /> <br />
    <br />
    Answer : <input name="Text1" type="text" value="$answer" /></form>
END_OF_FORM

?>
```

Comment: The form's `action` should be the URL of the page that will handle the form. In your case probaby `converter.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed file extension...

```
<form method="GET" action="converter.php">
```

Comment: I just facepalmed. I can't believe I missed that. I spent almost a half hour trying to figure out why it wouldn't work